# Numpy add with multiple arrays

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

Is there a way to *add* (as opposed to sum) multiple arrays together in a single operation? Obviously, `np.sum` and `np.add` are different operations, however, the problem I'm struggling with right now is that `np.add` only takes two arrays at once. I could utilize either

```
output = 0
for arr in arr_list:
    output = output + array
```

or

```
output = 0
for arr in arr_list:
    output = np.add(output, array)
```

and, yes, this is workable. However, it would be nice if I could simply do some variant of

```
output = np.add_multiple(arr_list)
```

Does this exist?

EDIT:
I failed to be clear initially. I specifically require a function that does *not* require an *array* of arrays to be constructed, as my arrays are not of equal dimensions and require broadcasting, for example:

```
a = np.arange(3).reshape(1,3)
b = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)

a, b = a[:,:,None,None], b[None,None,:,:]
```

These work:

```
a + b        # Works
np.add(a, b) # Works
```

These do *not*, and fail with the same exception:

```
np.sum([a, b], axis = 0)
np.add.reduce([a, b])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,1,1) into shape (1)
```

Comment: Where does that error come from?  I don't see an array with shape (3,1,1) defined anywhere.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it comes from `np.sum` and `np.add` calling `np.array` on the input array, in this case, `[a, b]`, and it's attempting to _cast_ it into rectangular arrays on every dimension as opposed to _broadcasting_ it.

Comment: @Firnagzen Actually I cannot reproduce the error you mentioned in the post. Are you sure the inputs `a` and `b` are correctly written?

Comment: Hey @GZ0, I made a mistake, yeah - the slicings were transposed. I've corrected it and verified that I get the error expected.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just use the Python's `sum` built-in:

```
output = sum(arr_list)
```

For many other `numpy` functions, [`np.<ufunc>.reduce`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) can be used as shown by @hpaulj.

Comment: To my immense surprise, this actually _does_ work. Thank you!

Comment: Interesting, why is Python's built-in sum function able to handle numpy arrays?

Comment: It's able to handle numpy arrays because numpy properly implements the necessary methods for python's arithmetic operations, specifically `.__add__()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `sum()` to add multiple arrays.

```
arr = np.array([[6,2,3,5,4,3], 
          [7,7,2,4,6,7],
          [10,6,2,4,5,9]])
np.add(0, arr.sum(axis=0))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this doesn't work! I was askinf for `add` for a specific reason that I wasn't clear about, my mistake.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the line `np.add(0, arr.sum(axis=0))` is doing two sums, the outer one (via `np.add`) doesn't do anything since it's just adding zeros... So, you could get the same result if you just do `arr.sum(axis=0)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [18]: alist = [np.arange(4),np.ones(4),np.array([10,1,11,2])]                
In [19]: np.add.reduce(alist)                                                   
Out[19]: array([11.,  3., 14.,  6.])
In [20]: alist[0]+alist[1]+alist[2]                                             
Out[20]: array([11.,  3., 14.,  6.])
```

And for more fun:

```
In [21]: np.add.accumulate(alist)                                               
Out[21]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [11.,  3., 14.,  6.]])
```

edit

---

```
In [53]: a.shape                                                                
Out[53]: (1, 1, 1, 3)
In [54]: b.shape                                                                
Out[54]: (3, 3, 1, 1)
```

Addition with broadcasting:

```
In [63]: sum([a,b]).shape                                                       
Out[63]: (3, 3, 1, 3)
In [64]: (a+b).shape                                                            
Out[64]: (3, 3, 1, 3)
In [66]: np.add.reduce([a,b]).shape                                             
Out[66]: (3, 3, 1, 3)
```

For what it's worth, I was suggesting `add.reduce` because I thought you wanted to add more than 2 arrays.

All these work as long as the arrays broadcast together.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this doesn't work! I was askinf for `add` for a specific reason that I wasn't clear about, my mistake.

Comment: It looks like the broardcasting fails if the first dimension of `a` and `b` match and does NOT need broadcasting, for some unknown reasons.

Comment: Given an example.  All of these approaches require the same broadcasting - the ability to do `a+b`.

Comment: Just a note @hpaulj, I _do_ actually want to add more than two arrays, I'm just using two in my examples since it's the most elementary.